# How do I get a view id from a dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog window where I have a spinner. Depending of the value selected in said spinner I have to load some elements or others to the layout. I have this method to do it, but the .setVisibility is not working:

```
        Spinner spinnerTypeQuestion = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuestionType);
    spinnerTypeQuestion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView wrapperRange;
            View viewQuestion = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_dialog, null);
            switch (position){
                case 0: // Range question
                    wrapperRange = (TextView) viewQuestion.findViewById(R.id.wrapperRange);
                    wrapperRange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 1: // Open answer
                    wrapperRange = (TextView) viewQuestion.findViewById(R.id.wrapperRange);
                    wrapperRange.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break; 
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });
```

Could you help me, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved my own question! I'm posting it in case someone faces the same problem.

Instead of using *viewQuestion* like I did:

```
wrapperRange = (TextView) viewQuestion.findViewById(R.id.wrapperRange);
```

You have to use your *dialog* as reference:

```
wrapperRange = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.wrapperRange);
```